# How to return two values in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, return-value

I currently return `liveDataName`, but I also want to return `liveDataImage`.

```
fun getProfileInfo(): LiveData<String> {

        val call: Call<UserProfile>? = NetworkService.getInstance()
                .jsonApi
                .getProfile()
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<UserProfile>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserProfile>, response: Response<UserProfile>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    response.body()?.let {
                        liveDataName.value = it.username
                        liveDataImage.value = it.defaultAvatar
                    }
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserProfile>, t: Throwable) {}
        })

        return liveDataName
    }
```

Comment: Return an array, list, dictionary  or other data structure. Same solution in every language (except those, like LUA, that actually allow to return multiple values).

Comment: See `Shadros` answer below. It shows a newer Kotlin feature to effectively return multiple values in a clean way.

Answer (score 7):

You could return a [`Pair`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/):

```kotlin
fun getProfileInfo(): Pair<LiveData<String>, LiveData<String>> {
  // ...
  return Pair(liveDataName, liveDataImage)
}
```

Comment: Or Triple if you want to return three values: return Triple(liveDataName, liveDataImage, foo)

Comment: The return type is wrong. It should be `Pair<LiveData<String>, LiveData<String>>`

Comment: and how to receive 2 vals ? For one value i used profileViewModel?.getProfileInformation()!!.observe(this, Observer {
            textViewProfile.text = it
        })  and now this code doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, when wanting to return `multiple values` it is the best to create a new class for that purpose. For example:

```
data class NameAndImage(val name: String, val image: String)
```

And then you could simply return `NameAndImage` from your function

```
fun getProfileInfo(): LiveData<NameAndImage> {
    return NameAndImage(liveDataName, liveDataImage)
}
```

To my mind, this is better than returning a Pair or a list, because you 100% know where which value is. You could just easily do `nameAndImage.name` which is better than `pair.data.first` where you have to think again what `first` was..

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin Pair/Triple class.

Kotlin has generic Pair and Triple types that can be used to return two or three values from the function. Note that it’s preferred to have your data named properly and a data class should be used to return more values.

```
fun fetchPersonDetails(): Triple<String, Int, Char> {
   val name = "Riya"
   val age = 18
   val gender = 'M'

   return Triple(name, age, gender)
}

fun main() {
   val (name: String, age: Int, gender: String) = fetchPersonDetails()

   println("($name, $age, $gender)")        // (Riya, 18, M)
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting, this destructuring feature can also extract values from a data class or collections.  For more details: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/returning-multiple-values